# Template and function pointer

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

Is it somehow possible to store the class from a template without making the the whole class a template?

Task:

I have two functions, v1 without parameters and v2 with parameters,
If v1 was called somewhere nothing happens with Use(), if v2 was called somewhere Use() should execute a function_ptr with the instance I got from DoSometh(T*).

e.g.

```
    class MyClass
    {
      //v1 no parameters
      void DoSomething()
      {
      }

      //v2 with parameter
      template<class T>
      void DoSomething(T* instance, void (T::*func)())
      {
        store somewhere?? = instance;
      }

      void Use()
      {
        //if DoSometh(T* instance) was used before
        if(instance != NULL)
        {
            (*instance->)//call function pointer from DoSomething(T*,void  (T::*)())
        }
      }
    }

std::function problem
update:


class Timer : public ITickable
{
  std::function<void()> test; //adding this does weird things

  virtual void Tick() {}
}

class MyClass
{
   ITickable* tickable_; 

void Tick()
{
    tickable_->Tick(); //let's assume it points to a Timer obj.
}


}
```

Comment: Do you *have* to use function pointers? Can't you use templates like the standard library uses for all its callable functions? Then you could pass a `std::function` object, generic functor objects, `std::bind` objects, normal (or static member) function pointers, and lambdas, all without worrying about instances or storing information.

Comment: `void *` or, even better - `ParentInterface *`

Comment: Show a real use case example. It seems like there may be a better solution altogether.

Comment: hmm, maybe there is a better solution overall, my main task is to create a Timer. right now I have a timer using std::chrono which runs for a amount of time and can be checked for isRunning / wasRunning, and now i want to add another function where its possible to add a function pointer which will be executed when timer is finished

Comment: Then perhaps a queue (or other appropriate container) of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) objects? Then let the user of the timer class [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) the correct function.

Comment: whats the difference between std::function and  a function_ptr

Comment: @slei Type erasure, i.e what you're trying to do. `std::function` wraps any callable object of a given signature.

Comment: hmm i have no idea how to use std::function & bind on my example

Comment: What does "//use instance e.g. for a func_ptr" mean? It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do you need a pre-specified signature of the function that executes when the timer is finished?

Comment: updated, if DoSomething(T...) is called, it should call the function pointer from DoSomething(...) in function Use()

Comment: @JorenHeit well i'm not sure the call somewhere should look like this:
e.g. in class MyClass: 
`Timer.DoSomething(time_to_wait, this, &MyClass::MyFunction );`

Comment: I understand, but does `MyClass::MyFunction` have a predetermined signature? I.e. do you *know* that for example it's a `void ()`? Or could it be anything?

Comment: but i think, like others said, it's not possible to store the class I get from the templace function, so I have to find another design :(

Comment: @slei I'm trying to figure out something for you, but in order to do so, I have to know what the constraints of your problem are.

Comment: @JorenHeit just MyFunction(), without parameters, so every function is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `std::function` and `std::bind` (C++11) do accomplish what you want, as already suggested in the comments. A simplified mock-up of your Timer class could be:

```
class Timer
{
    std::function<void()> m_task;

public:
    template <typename T>
    void setTask(T &instance, void (T::*fcn)()) // consider T const & if applicable
    {
        m_task = std::bind(fcn, &instance);
    }

    void fire()
    {
        if (m_task) // std::function overloads operator bool()                                                                          
            m_task();
    }
};
```

When `setTask` is called with an object and a member-function that can be called on this object, a `std::function` object is created (you could choose to do this in a constructor of course). When the timer fires, this object is checked (using `operator bool()`, provided by `std::function`), and if it is callable (e.g. when `setTask()` has been called before), it calls the function.

For example:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        std::cout << "Hi from MyClass\n";
    }
};

class MyOtherClass
{
public:
    void func()
    {
        std::cout << "Hi from MyOtherClass\n";
    }
};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    MyClass x1;
    MyOtherClass x2;

    Timer t1, t2;
    t1.setTask(x1, &MyClass::func);
    t2.setTask(x2, &MyOtherClass::func);

    t1.fire();
    t2.fire();
}
```

Comment: hmm, somehow when i write std::function<void()> m_task; in my class definition, nothing works anymore

Comment: is there a problem with inheritance and std::function?

Comment: what if e.g. Timer has a base class ITickable?
`class Timer : public ITickable {}`

might this cause problems?

Comment: Did you `#include <functional>`? Inheritance should not make any difference

Comment: yeah, code compiles, but corrupts everything, by adding std::function... to the child class

Comment: That's really weird. And I would almost say impossible. Just adding a `std::function` as a member should not make any difference. When do things go wrong? When you call `operator()` on the `std::function`-object? Or even before that?

Comment: I have no idea why, where and when, but adding the std::function declaration is enough
`std::function<void()> m_task;`

Comment: And what exactly happens when you do that?

Comment: i actually have no idea, some static strings get corrupted, and my Tick() function in the Timer class which gets called each frame doesn't work anymore.
updated question with some new code

Comment: can you post a live example that shows the behavior you talk about? For example on https://ideone.com/

Comment: Just in case: when you call `operator()` on a `std::function` object that hasn't been initialized, it will throw an exception. Is your application catching/ignoring exceptions at any point? If so, are you indeed calling `operator()` on the object anywhere?

Comment: ok, well it was a stupid "bug", a clean did the job and now everything works...

your solution works percetly, thank you :)

Comment: Ah I see :-) Glad it works now! Feel free to accept/upvote the answer ;-)